# Making a checkbox using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a checkBox using AngularJS, I found this code :
http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/211/

and following its steps my code was :

JS File:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp.Carto', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Carto', {
            templateUrl: 'Carto/carto.html',
            controller: 'CartoCtrl'
        });
    }])

app.controller('CartoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [];
    $scope.array_ = angular.copy($scope.array);
    $scope.list = [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "apple",
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "orange",
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "value": "pear"
    }];



});
app.directive("checkboxGroup", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            // Determine initial checked boxes
            if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                elem[0].checked = true;
            }

            // Update array on click
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                // Add if checked
                if (elem[0].checked) {
                    if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
                }
                // Remove if unchecked
                else {
                    if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                }
                // Sort and update DOM display
                scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a - b;
                }));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, when I run the code in the browser the checkbox appears but I can't chack the boxes, does that mean the directive doesn't work ? 
I could'nt figure out what was going wrong because I practically just copied the code in the link provided above , can you please help me how to fix this ?

Thank you in advance

PS: I think it's due to materialize but I still don't know how or how to fix it

Comment: what kind of errors do you see in the console?. You need to link the angular library in the script tag of your html and also instantiate angular module by linking the module name 'checkbox'  to your html or body tag

Comment: @WildWidow  There is no error in console it's empty

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3906/
I think you're mixing up the module names btw.

Comment: @WildWidow The angular library is imported in index.html which this file inherits from, in my case I don't have a module named 'checkbox' , I put its code in module 'myApp.Carto' that's why in html I put ng-app = "myApp"

Comment: @Matheno did you change anything ?

Comment: I used your code, but with the right module names.

Comment: @Matheno ok I'll see if it works

Comment: Your code is also working fine, just add {{array}}
http://jsbin.com/poriyobari/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @fruitjs I copied exactly what you said and it still doesn't click

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a mistake with the module name.
I recreated your sample code and it works perfectly fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3906/)

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.array = [];
  $scope.array_ = angular.copy($scope.array);
  $scope.list = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "apple",
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "value": "orange",
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "value": "pear"
  }];
}

myApp.directive("checkboxGroup", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      // Determine initial checked boxes
      if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
        elem[0].checked = true;
      }

      // Update array on click
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
        // Add if checked
        if (elem[0].checked) {
          if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
        }
        // Remove if unchecked
        else {
          if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
        }
        // Sort and update DOM display
        scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a - b
        }));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group />
    <label>{{item.value}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run your code, it says :
[ng:areq] Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: How do you declare your module/app? This error is usually thrown when you declare your app twice.

Comment: in the fiddle, all of them work but in my project I don't seem to figure out why it doesn't work

Comment: Could it be linked to something else ? why it doesn't click ?

Comment: That is possible. But we need to see the rest of the code to be sure.

Comment: My real code is in the post, I'll modify it to include the whole JS file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111765/discussion-between-jean-and-matheno).

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the presence of both bootstrap and Materialize , apparently there is a conflict between the two and when I deleted bootstrap, it all worked well